# How can we load an originally serial list (not sorted) into combo box from mysql usin Java?

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void loadCombo() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstat = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
    try {
        con = Get_MySQL_Connection.get_Connection();
        String query = "Select designation from designations";
        pstat = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pstat.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            lst.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        Object[] arr = lst.toArray();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(arr);

        cmbDesignation.setModel(model);
        cmbDesignation.insertItemAt("Select One", 0);
        cmbDesignation.setSelectedIndex(0);
        cmbDesignation.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I write this code combo box shows alphabetically sorted list like

```
AGM, GM, Office, Senior Officer, etc
```

but I need list like

```
GM, AGM, Senior Officer, Officer
```

Comment: The first result  expresses the order in which your data is stored in the database, and its not alphabetically ordered, and `jComboBox` isn't sorted by default.

Comment: Have you executed `Select designation from designations` on the database? I'd think that designation is a key in your table - and sorting by a key makes sense for most databases.

Comment: No, designation is not a key in my database.

Comment: Then what is? Please give table description and data.